# Vertically stacking two images in a single subfloat

Tags: subfloats

I would like to have this arrangement

[image]

I don't really know the format of subfloats but I have this idea

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfloat[\centering ]{\includegraphics[height=.2\textheight]{example-image-a}
                            \includegraphics[height=.2\textheight]{example-image-b}}
    \subfloat[\centering ]{\includegraphics[height=.4\textheight]{example-image-c} }
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:wa_analysis}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Not entirely certain how to accomplish this.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Please extend your code to a full but minimal example and please use images that others have access to (or use `\rule{width}{height}`) when we know wher `\subfloat` etc came from.

Comment: Sorry, new to this. Done.

Comment: Your document does not compile as it does not define `\subfloat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{minipage}{.65\textwidth}
            \begin{center}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=5cm]{example-image-a}\\
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=5cm]{example-image-b}
                (a)
            \end{center}
        \end{minipage}
        \hfill
        \begin{minipage}{.33\textwidth}
            \begin{center}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=10cm]{example-image-c}
                (b)
            \end{center}
        \end{minipage}
        \caption{Test fo 3 figure in one}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

You have this output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

By use the `subcaption` package and some manula tweak for `subfigure` b height:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.7\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,  height=.2\textheight]{example-image-a}\\
      
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,  height=.2\textheight]{example-image-b}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfil                           
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=.423\textheight]{example-image-c}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}  
                          
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:wa_analysis}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would use `minipage` to stack two subfigures. In order to avoid guessing the height of the third figure, you can also use a box

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[tbh]
  \sbox0{%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.75\textwidth}
      \subcaptionbox*{}{\includegraphics[height=0.2\textheight,width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
      \par
      \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[height=0.2\textheight,width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
  \end{minipage}}
  \usebox0
  \hfill%
  \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[height=\ht0,width=.22\textwidth]{example-image-c}}
  \caption{Caption}
  \label{fig:wa_analysis}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

This version uses `\subfloat` from the subcaption package.  It seems that subfloat uses an `\hbox` instead of a `\vbox`, so you need a `minipage`, `\parbox`, `\vbox` or `tabular` to handle more than one line.

`\lineskip` is added when `\baselineskip` isn't big enough.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \subfloat{\parbox{.65\textwidth}{%
          \includegraphics[width=\hsize,height=5cm]{example-image-a}
          \includegraphics[width=\hsize,height=5cm]{example-image-b}
         }}
        \hfill
        \subfloat{%
          \includegraphics[width=.33\textwidth,height={\dimexpr 10cm+\lineskip}]{example-image-c}
        }
        \caption{Test fo 3 figure in one}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```